# Python EVE aggregation not working

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, eve, mongodb-aggregation

I am using Eve to create a RESTful API for MongoDB. Maybe I am doing something wrong, but I cant figure out why Eve is not returning me aggregated results. Below is my DOMAIN:

```
DOMAIN = {
    'heartbeats': {
        'schema': {
            'user': {
                'type': 'objectid',
                'required': True,
            },
            'device': {
                'type': 'objectid',
                'required': True,
            },
            'pir': {
                'type': 'integer'
            },
            'camera': {
                'type': 'integer'
            },
            'image': {
                'type': 'media',
                'required':False
            }
        }
    },
    'chart1' : {
        'datasource':{
            'source' : 'heartbeats',
            'aggregation' : {
                'pipeline': [
                    {"$group" : {"_id":"$user", "count" : {"$sum" : 1}}}
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when querying it from browser I get just all the records, not aggregated results.

[image]

Why am I not getting aggregated results??

Comment: Whoever demoted it, can you please express your view as to why? Or you are one of those who just goes on and rank questions randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On which Eve version are you? MongoDB Aggregation Framework support is currently on the development branch. If you are using any of the stable versions (v0.6.4 being the latest), you won't get aggregation support. Try installing the development branch.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me check the version I am using later today. Is there a timeline for it to be promoted to stable?
Amazing work by the way! Love the project.